# Type force conversion in collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have encountered a complex generics problem:
Supporsed two collection references, A and B, which definitions as follows:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>>  A = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map> B = new ArrayList<>();
```

next, put all the items of B into A, but this is not work straightly without a force type conversion with javac.

```java
A.addAll((C)B);
```

So, what the C should be in this situation which is compatible with javac.

(I'm maintaining the old code of the old project in the company, and I don't know why the author coded it in this way. [tear])

Comment: You do realise that `B` is a raw type here, right? Are you _sure_ that this is safe? Can you/Why can't you declare `B` to be of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead?

Comment: This is the old code and I don't want to change the code too many. Changes may introduce bugs! So, change the C is safer.

Comment: In this case it won't introduce any bugs. You only changing type, not behavior. It even can help you find existing bugs.

Comment: Agree with @talex that it's a bad idea.  Changing the type of B is likely less bug prone than casting and putting into A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List<Map<String, Object>>` to cast.

```
A.addAll((List<Map<String, Object>>)(Object)B);
```

Extra cast to `Object` needed to explain to compiler who is the boss here.